# Logged in but not?

Tags: bug

I suspect a bug, but perhaps a WAD (Works As Designed).

The top bar showed my photo and rep as if I was logged in (image below), but I was not able to enter a comment nor an answer.  In trying to figure out why, I discovered I was **not** logged in (or more precisely, a log-in link was offered and it gave me a log-in form).  After submitting that form, the top bar still looked the same, but I was allowed to save my comment.
[image: account tool bar]

Comment: Can you please show us a screenshot of what you see? That might be helpful. Also, is the problem still happening?

Comment: I've had something similar before on the mobile site but never been able to reproduce it.